# How to get Seagate 4TB(ST4000DM000) to work on new computer?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I moved my Seagate 4TB disk to a new computer, I have installed Intel rapid storage technology and I have installed the Seagate tools.  I can see my disk in both Intel's software as well as in Seagate's tool (SeaGate DiscWizard).

I have the option to format the disk to make it work but that isn't really an option because I have a 1.2TB of pictures, games, movies, TV-shows etc.

Reverting to the old machine is not an option either, so anyone got any experience in getting the disk working on the new machine?

Both the old and the new machine is running Windows. I can even see the partitions in the Seagate tool but not in the Windows tool, Ubuntu disk utility or GParted.

When I look in the disk utility tool I get this:

[image]

And when I try mounting the disk in the terminal I get this:

[image]

And lastly, when I try mounting with ntfs-3g I get this:

[image]

I've also tried to use `/dev/sda1`, `sda2` and `sda3` but none of them work.

Here are screenshots of GParted for both disks:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Due to the lack of clarity and the spelling mistakes its hard to understand what your actual question is.

Comment: The question in simpler terms is as following: how do i get my seagate  4tb disk to work on a new computer without having to reformat it ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything.  It should simply work.  We need to know more about the "new" machine.

Comment: Well its nothing special about it, the same problem was when i tried to install the drives in the first machine. The only thing of use i can tell you is that in the disk manager in windows it says the disk in a dynamic disk and that its invalid.

Comment: I was easily able to find a solution by doing a google [search](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26829-convert-dynamic-disk-basic-disk.html)

Comment: And you are sure that will make me able to read my disks content ?

Comment: You have not provided enough information for me to guarantee anything.  You wanted to know how to convert a dynamic partition to a basic partition.

Comment: Well the convertion dident work, i got an error saying the conversion failed, and im sorry if im giving to little information but theres nothing more to tell

Comment: Lets start with the exact error.  Update your question.

Comment: I've tediously copied information from your previous question here. Next time please try and keep all info related to one problem in one post. Having multiple questions with the same issue isn't helping—people are going to ask you for missing info on both, and it's all a big mess. Thanks for sticking to that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If the Windows, Ubuntu, AND gparted utilities are failing to see your partitions, your partition table is most likely broken or altered to the point where it is unrecognizable and will need to be repaired before you can access your partitions again. The only reason the Seagate tool is still able to see them is probably because the utility is taking into account any inconsistencies in the table and displaying raw disk information.

My suggestion is to use some form of linux live disk (Ubuntu, Arch, knoppix, etc.) that has the `fdisk` utility and try to see if that can read the partitions on your disk to verify the current condition of the disk. If your partition table is broken, then all that will be displayed in the volume with no partition information. If the partitions are displayed, then perhaps your disk was not cleanly unmounted, try mounting it and unmounting normally and reinserting it into the Windows machine.

If your partition table is broken, there are a few utilities that can be used to help restore it, or at least attempt to:

1. fdisk - You can recreate both the partition table and the relevant partitions using fdisk manually, there is plenty of documentation online on how fdisk works and is beyond the scope of this question.
2. [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) - Open source utility that is well documented and supported
3. Various Windows partition recovery utilities, a lot have free trials, but they tend to be rather bloaty pieces of software